# Фабрика создания бинов с дженериком spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

Есть подключение бина через @Autowire.

```java
@Autowired
private Service<SomeClass> service;
```

Для `Service<SomeClass>` создаётся вручную имплементация. При этом чаще всего имеет стандартную реализацию через абстрактный класс `AbstractService`.

Можно ли создать некоторую фабрику в spring boot, которая будет создавать сервис налету, если имплементация такого интерфейса отсутствует?

Из всей документации я не понял как:

1. показать spring'у, что фабрика может делать объекты вида `Service<?>` (т.е. с дженериком)
2. получить какой конкретно класс у дженерика (`SomeClass`)

**Уточнение**
Хотелось бы реализовать следующее поведение Spring DI:

1. Видим `@Autowired private Service<SomeClass> service;`, смотрим наличие бина в контексте.
2. Если не нашли, обращаемся к фабрике, которая нам создаст и вернёт нужный бин.

Не понимаю можно ли написать такую фабрику

Comment: `если имплементация такого интерфейса отсутствует` - отсутствует где? Нет бина в контексте? Или нет класса в classpath? Что касается получения параметра дженерика (`SomeClass` из такого определения как в вопросе), то это невозможно - ограничение реализации дженериков в java. После компиляции класса с полем `service` в скомпилированном классе нет никакого упоминания `SomeClass` (оно стирается - гуглите erasure, и на этом сайте были вопросы в том числе) и в runtime через reflection получить параметр нельзя. Я не до конца понимаю изначальную задачу (вы ее не описали) чтоб предложить решение

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, если нет бина в контексте, чтобы CDI обратился к фабрике, которая его может сделать. В фабрику в качестве параметра хотелось бы получить имя класса `SomeClass`, без него фабрика не сможет создать бин.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, хочется получить некий симбиоз `FactoryBean` и `org.springframework.core.ResolvableType`